# Custom Heroes Ascended Forms

Tags: custom-heroes

Custom Heroes is a new game (2017), and I need some clarification, if you were a playtester, rules writer, or game designer for it.

An Ascended Form can be played to beat any previous play. The rulebook example says "After an ascended form is used, play continues around the table as normal, though only another ascended form may beat a previously played ascended form ...."

It's the word `normal` that puzzles me. Is it simply referring to the order of play, or does it mean that the ascended form is like a wild card, but after that players can return to the basic pattern, for example

```
four 8s
ascended form
four 9s
```

I don't believe that's what it means, but if not, then playing an ascended form will quickly terminate that round/pile. It would be a power play to try to force the ascended forms into the shuffle.  Is that the idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing an Ascended Form can indeed shorten the round.

What that sentence means is that an Ascended Form does not immediately end the round. The round continues, but the only legal play is another Ascended Form  (which causes the following player's turn to be skipped, etc). One must match or beat the current set, and only an Ascended Form matches or beats an Ascended Form.

That said, an Ascended Form does immediately end the round in a two-player game. In a two-player game, you need to beat (not match) the current set, and nothing beats an Ascended Form.